# I need a preprocess function to inject category name in my node

Tags: nodes, theming

Hello I need to display the category name of the article (it is in taxonomy) inside my node. Here is the function

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
        $node = $vars['node'];
        $vars['category'] = "category here..";
    }
```

With my devel_themer module I manage to find out where this category is:

field[image]

Please if someone help me how to insert the category in $vars['category'] thanks!

Comment: What are you kpr/dpr/krumo/dpm'ing?